# Como combinar diversos arquivos R-Markdown (.rmd) em um único documento?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Em um projeto no R, tenho diversos arquivos `.Rmd` em uma mesma pasta. Como no exemplo abaixo:

**Capitulo1.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Capítulo 1"
output: pdf_document
---

# Esse é o capítulo 1. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

**Capitulo2.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Capítulo 2"
output: pdf_document
---

# Esse é o capítulo 2. 

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Como unir/compilar todos os capítulos em um único arquivo `.pdf` ?

*Nota: pergunta e resposta [adaptadas do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824795/how-to-combine-two-rmarkdown-rmd-files-into-a-single-output), com a finalidade de sistematizar o conhecimento mais recente sobre o tema para a comunidade de língua portuguesa, conforme diretrizes sugeridas por três debates do Meta SOpt, nos links: [1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs), [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs), e [3](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3746/%c3%89-v%c3%a1lido-traduzir-uma-resposta-do-stackoverflow-em-ingl%c3%aas) .*

Answer (score 1):

#### Pacote bookdown

Uma opção é a utilização do pacote **bookdown**, elaborado especialmente para a escrita de livros e relatórios longos no R-markdown, e que inclui diversas funcionalidades como a possibilidade de referências cruzadas entre os capítulos.

Para juntar os diversos os diversos arquivos `.Rmd`, cria-se um novo arquivo denominado `index.Rmd` na mesma pasta na qual estão localizados os demais arquivos `.Rmd` do projeto. Nesse arquivo `index.Rmd`, devemos incluir uma linha adicional no YAML: `site:bookdown::bookdown_site` . Quando compilarmos o arquivo `index.Rmd` o pacote bookdown irá juntar todos os arquivos `.Rmd` que estão na mesma pasta, em ordem alfabética. Há duas exceções: a primeira é o arquivo `index.Rmd`, sempre o primeiro a ser compilado. A segunda são os arquivos iniciados com subscrito, por exemplo `_teste.Rmd`, que são ignorados.

**index.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Meu livro escrito no R"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: yes
---

# Prefácio:
```

**Capitulo1.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Capítulo 1"
output: pdf_document
---

# Capítulo 1 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```
````

**Capitulo2.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Capítulo 2"
output: pdf_document
---

# Capítulo 2

```{r}
plot(pressure)
```
````

**Escolhendo quais arquivos compilar e modificando sua ordem**

Caso você deseje unir os arquivos em uma ordem diferente da ordem alfabética, ou deixar algum arquivo `.Rmd` do projeto de fora da compilação final, é possível fazer isso alterando o arquivo `_bookdown.yml` . No caso, vamos supor que você queira enviar para um grupo de estudos apenas o prefácio e os capítulos 2 e 5 do seu livro. Você pode fazer isso adicionando o campo `rmd_files` no arquivo `_bookdown.yml`:

```
rmd_files: ["index.Rmd", "Capitulo2.Rmd", "Capitulo5.Rmd"]
```

Essa estratégia é especialmente útil se você deseja produzir duas publicações em formatos diferentes que utilizam arquivos `.Rmd` do mesmo projeto. Por exemplo, se você quiser publicar seu livro/relatório em HTML e também em PDF, você pode especificar uma sequencia diferente de arquivos para ser compilada para cada formato:

```
rmd_files:
  html: ["index.Rmd", "Capitulo1.Rmd", "Capitulo2.Rmd"]
  latex: ["index.Rmd", "Capitulo1.Rmd",  "Capitulo2.Rmd", "ZAnexoA.Rmd"]
```

Para maiores detalhes, consultar [a documentação do pacote bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) (fonte complementar das informações desta resposta).